# Use background-color of parent as box-shadow color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an "enhanced" radio button by use of an inset `box-shadow`.

[Here's a CodePen of what I got so far](http://codepen.io/selbekk/pen/NxXNoK?editors=110)

What I'm trying to do is to make the background of the `.radio-button` `<div />` be used as the color of the `box-shadow`. In my current solution, the color is set to `#fff`, which works on a white background, but not when the background is gray.

- Setting it to `currentColor` sets the color of the box shadow to the `border-color` value, which is `#333`;
- Setting it to `inherit` seems to disable the box-shadow, at least in Chrome. Makes sense in a way I guess, i'm assuming `inherit` doesn't work for parts of a property like here.
- Not setting it at all defaults it to the value of `color`, which is black.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do without JavaScript?

Comment: but, if the shadow is the same color as the background, it won't show  ... I must be missing something here .

Comment: @vals - I want to avoid having the radio button care about the background color of its parent - therefore the box shadow has to be inherited from its parent's background color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS does not provide a special value that corresponds to the computed background color of an element akin to `currentColor` (which corresponds to the *foreground* color; that is, `color` — it shouldn't be corresponding to `border-color` even if it's set to a different value to `color`).

You could cheat by setting `color` to the desired background color and `background-color: currentColor` along with the box shadow, putting the label text in its own element within the `label` element, and giving that new element the intended font color.

---

The `inherit` keyword can only exist by itself in a CSS declaration. It cannot be used as a single component in a set of values. This means while box shadows *can* inherit, the entire `box-shadow` property must be inherited in full. When that happens, what ends up inherited is the box shadow of the parent element — which won't work either since the parent has no box shadow.

Comment: OK maybe I'm not reading the structure of elements correctly (it's late), but the discrepancy in `currentColor` might be due to how `currentColor` is calculated wrt parent vs child elements, and inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, great answer - albeit not what I hoped for. I'll try to create what I'm making in another way :)

Answer (score 1):

I still don't fully understand what are you trying to do ...

May be something like that ?

```css
.test {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, white 10px, transparent 30px);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px black;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 90px, green 90px, green 180px, blue 120px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Good approach - but this was what I ended up doing: http://codepen.io/selbekk/pen/jWYrzB?editors=110

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't provide much ability to create the 'padding of transparency' that you are looking for, however there is a way with a pseudo-element.
You need to drop the box-shadow and any background on the circle, and instead envisage the central dot as a separate element that will 'float' on top:

```
.radio-button-input + .radio-button-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: .8em;
  height: .8em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color .1s ease-out;
  position: relative;
}

.radio-button-input + .radio-button-circle:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color .1s ease-out;
  width: .55em;
  height: .55em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%
}

.radio-button-input:checked + .radio-button-circle:after {
  background-color: #333;
}
```