# How can I achieve a border tilted from the button?

Tags: css

I want to achieve a button where there will a border behind the button. I have gone through many methods but the closest one is **Using Box Shadows** the code looks something like this:

```
.button-with-bg-outline-shadow a{
    box-shadow:
   12px 8px 0 0px #042036,
   14px 7px 0 0px var(--e-global-color-a29f98a ),
   14px 9px 0 0px var(--e-global-color-a29f98a ),
   10px 8px 0 0px var(--e-global-color-a29f98a );
   transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

but the problem with this is when I have different background, I need to change colors in the box-shadow property and thus I need to write new CSS for every button separately.

Demo: https://imgur.com/j9BChj4

I want the area covered by the outline should be transparent so that I can reuse one element everywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use background-color of parent as box-shadow color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907554/use-background-color-of-parent-as-box-shadow-color)

Comment: You don't need box shadow to achieve this effect. Use `:after` to make the border and to set it behind the button.

Comment: Thank you. I was unable to find out how to achieve with the :after method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pseudo-element by inheriting some of its parent's properties. Then apply a mask to cut out the inner area.

```css
/* Only for example --> */ body { margin: 0; display: grid; place-items: center; min-height: 100vh; background: 0 0 / cover url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWGMC.jpg'); }

a {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100px; width: 550px;
  border-radius: 23px;
  font: bold 40px/1em sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px; left: 23px; z-index: -1;
  height: inherit; width: inherit;
  border: 3px solid #0000;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  --mask: linear-gradient(#000 0 0), linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-image: var(--mask);
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
  mask-image: var(--mask);
  mask-size: 100% 100%;
  mask-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  mask-composite: exclude;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Book An Appotment</a>
```

Comment: UModeL, If I change the width and height, it doesn't seem to work properly, Any solution for that?

Comment: @RakibulHashan, Whose dimensions are you changing - an element or a pseudo-element?

Answer (score 0):

Use `:after` + css variables + `currentColor`. This is funcy buttons :

```css
button {
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 32px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform .4s;
  font-weight: 700;
  will-change: transform;
}

button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 8px -8px -8px 8px;
  border: solid 2px currentColor;
  border-radius: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: transform .4s;
}

button:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

button span {
  color: var(--text-color, #fff);
  z-index: 1;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translate(2px, 2px);
}

button:hover:before {
  transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
}

button:active {
  transform: translate(4px, 4px);
}

button:active:before {
  transform: translate(-4px, -4px);
}
```

```html
<button style="color: blue;">
  <span>Button Red</span>
</button>
<br>
<button style="color: lightblue; --text-color:black;">
  <span>Button Red</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This works for me. But it seems like if the :after color is something different it appears at the top of the button.

Comment: I saw it and fixed it 